# getting "ORA-01017: invalid username/password;logon denied" exception after installing Zulu

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to establish an oracle database connection using connection string

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HOSTNAME)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICENAME)));User Id=/;
```

in C# native application. Here I am using operating system authentication.

When I was using jdk1.8, it was working fine but since I moved to zulu8, it is throwing exception

> "ORA-01017: invalid username/password;logon denied".

This is the only change that happened over the period.

I am clueless how to solve this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the connection string is not providing the full credentials. Connecting locally to oracle you can use `/` as a qualifying username and password via sqlplus, as the database is configured by default to do that. Otherwise, you have to specify the full username and password:

you can go here and get a good format for your connection string as if varies based on your connection method:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/